# Impossible to override user-select on child nodes?

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a CSS rule that makes the default behaviour to not allow selection of text or elements on a page. I then add a rule for specific nodes (such as paragraphs or header text) to allow text selection on them.

Unfortunately this does not work as expected and it seems impossible to override this setting on a child node.

Check this jsfiddle to see what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/cH8WD/

Any idea how I can get this to work properly?

Thanks

Edit:

To better illustrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/cH8WD/5/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try "text" instead of "normal" like:

```
* {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -khtml-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -o-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

edit: for FireFox, i changed the line "-moz-user-select: none;" to "-moz-user-select: -moz-none;"

Comment: It makes no difference. You can try this on jsfiddle yourself just by modifying the values in my version.

Comment: i tried it with Chrome and it worked for me. "normal" didn't work but "text" worked. i'll check with other browsers now.

Comment: Ok, I'm testing on Firefox which has the same problem whether it's "normal", "text", "auto" or anything else. Unfortunately I'd need a solution that'd work across all browsers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! How did you manage to figure that one out? Firefox having a "-moz-none" that operates differently from "none" isn't exactly intuitive.

Comment: i have some documentations/links for browser compitibility issues. i just checked my firefox compitibility problems folder and saw that "-moz-none" as a similar solution.

Comment: Starting with Firefox 21 none behaves like -moz-none.